# codeignigter use rest to pass data to external site

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, post, get

OK in plain PHP I use the following to pass data to a GET

```
file_get_contents('https://ws.mysite.com/some.svc/here?userID=' . $session_id . '&score=' . $percentilescore . '&assessmentID=' . $testID . '&assessmentTitle=some');
```

I now want to apply this same piece of code to my CI project.

This Is how I have tried.

```
private function getResults()
    {

        $score = $this->actions->getSentEmailCount();
        $percentilescore = $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $testID = '134';
        $percentile = $this->actions->getPercentile($score);
        $time = $this->input->get('time');
        $timemath = 60000;
        $timeinmseconds =  $time * $timemath;



        $adddata = array(
            'uniID' => '5',
            'testName' => 'some',
            'testID' => $testID,
            'total' => '10',
            'correct' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'percent' => $score = $this->actions->getScore(),
            'dateTaken' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'timeSpent' => $timeinmseconds,
            'userID' => $session_id,
        );

        $this->actions->add_record($adddata);
        return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);

        file_get_contents('https://ws.mysite.com/123.svc/some?userID=' . $session_id . '&score=' . $percentilescore . '&assessmentID=' . $testID . '&assessmentTitle=some');

    }
```

It is not posting the data any idea why and how I should do it in CI ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` should be the last statement in the function because it's immediately ends execution of the current function. Just put `file_get_contents` before return:

```
file_get_contents('https://ws.mysite.com/123.svc/some?userID=' . $session_id . '&score=' . $percentilescore . '&assessmentID=' . $testID . '&assessmentTitle=some');

$this->actions->add_record($adddata);
return $this->load->view('client/results', $data);
```